# How to configure JBoss to connect to external activeMQ broker?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, activemq-classic

I've read lots of documentation about ActiveMQ and the integration into JBoss.
I'm bot able to know if the only way to configure the connection to remote broker is to modify the `ra.xml` from the activeMQ rar connector ?

- Is it possible to specify the remote broker with another kind of configuration ?
- Should I have to create a new rar connector specific to my application distribution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The configuration is done during the maven assembly process:

I have a specific `ra.ml` that I inject into deflated `activemq-rar.rar\META-INF` directory.